# php mysql_fetch_array() error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in-select)

I am getting this error while i am trying to delete a record the query is working but this line remains on the page. i want to echo "Deleted" written in the while should show up but the while loop is not working, i have tried and searched alot nothing helps!

```
 mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in delete.php on line 27
```

**delete.php**

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="post">
Id : <input type="text" name="id">
Name : <input type="text" name="name">
Description  : <input type="text" name="des">
<input type="submit" value="delete" name="delete">
</form>
<?php 
include("connect.php");
 $id = $_POST['id'];
 $name = $_POST['name'];
 $des = $_POST['des'];

 $result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM fact WHERE id='$id'") or die(mysql_error());

 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {

   echo "Deleted";
   }

 mysql_close($con);  ?>
 </body>
 </html>
```

**connect.php**

```
<?php 
  $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
 if (!$con)
    {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
   mysql_select_db("Dataentry", $con);
  ?>
```

How should i make the while loop work..

Comment: Also: **SQL INJECTION VULNERABILITY!**

Comment: Also: **mysql_* functions are deprecated!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you run a `DELETE` command, I believe nothing is returned, thus you can't mysql_fetch_array(). You would normally use that if you're doing a `SELECT`. in this case, you're deleting something, so just remove that loop, and echo().

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that a delete statement doesn't produce a result set!

```
$result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM fact WHERE id='$id'") or die(mysql_error());
if (mysql_affected_rows() > 0)
{
    echo 'Record deleted!';
}
```

Also: As mentioned in the comments, you are vulnerable to SQL injection, and also using a deprecated extension. Please have a look through [this awesome post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/1207346) for some guidance on these issues.

Comment: This one worked for me .. thx .. but i have to remove the while loop now

Comment: @user1877823 Yes, there is no need for a while loop because there are no "results" to loop through :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Dont use mysql_* functions, use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) or [Mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead.
2. [take care](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) about $id value. [more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection)
3. we use mysql_fetch_array for fetching return result of SELECT Queries.

You may want this

```
if(mysql_affected_rows()  > 0)
{
   echo "Deleted";
}
else
{
  echo "An error occured.";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <html>
   <body>
    <form method="post">
      Id : <input type="text" name="id">
       Name : <input type="text" name="name">
   Description  : <input type="text" name="des">
     <input type="submit" value="delete" name="delete">
   </form>
   <?php 
    include("connect.php");
     $id = $_POST['id'];
     $name = $_POST['name'];
     $des = $_POST['des'];

   $result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM fact WHERE id='$id'") or die(mysql_error());

    if($result) //if(mysql_affected_rows($result) > 0)
    {

       echo "Deleted";
    }
    else
    {
        echo mysql_error();
    }

    mysql_close($con);  ?>
   </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use mysql_* function, Try PDO example

```
<?php
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'user', 'password');
$count = $dbh->exec("DELETE FROM fact WHERE id='$id'");
if($count > 0){
    echo 'Deleted';
}else{
    echo 'Not Deleted';
}
?>
```

$count will return no. of rows deleted

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM fact WHERE id='$id'") or die(mysql_error());

if($result)
{
    echo "Deleted";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

in some time die create problem so you use it like this 
**$result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM fact WHERE id='$id'");**